# GKAchievementViewController full screen (or PageSheet) odd display

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I am working with the iPad at the moment and am using Cocos2D.  Up until now I have just been testing with the default view when dealing with Game Center.  I am attempting to now set it up as I want it, which is using either full screen or PageSheet (which is shown in the image).

My question(s) is fairly simple (at least in the asking).  Why exactly is it doing that?  I can not figure out how to access that "wooden" frame that is drawing over top of achievement view.

[image: Example image]

Here is the code I have been using (including random stuff I have been trying) to get to a bigger view.

```
- (void)showAchievements:(id)sender
{   
    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (achievements != nil)
    {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = self;

        tempVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//      tempVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

//      tempVC.interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        [achievements shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        [achievements shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

        [tempVC shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        [tempVC shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];


//      achievements.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
//      tempVC.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        tempVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        tempVC.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width, winSize.height);
//      tempVC.view.superview
//      tempVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
//      achievements.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        achievements.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
//      achievements.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        achievements.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
//      achievements. = CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width, winSize.height);

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tempVC.view];
        [tempVC presentModalViewController:achievements animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My understanding of UIKit is extremely limited.  I use Cocos2D and Box2D and pretty much nothing else (up until now anyway).  Please, any help you can provide will be very much appreciated.  If you could simply show me how this would be done properly (without all the junk code I have in there) that would be perfect.

Thank you :)

Comment: I asked this and then got very sick for about a week or so and I come back and not so much as a comment.  Hopefully a bounty will get me an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to do this with UIModalPresentationPageSheet and I see the same result, it's not just you. The "correct" way to do this is not to change the size of the modal view! :) Apple's UI designers have chosen their desired presentation style & size of the achievements view; it's best not to mess with that, for consistency between games.

Comment: Yeah sometimes I wish I could slap them up the back of the head.  I am going to leave the question open for a while in the hopes I can get a work-around.

Comment: I don't really recommend trying to work around it. Why do you really want to circumvent their desired design? Also, [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com)! :)

Comment: On the iPad the modal display for Game Kit is REALLY small.  It would be way better to use much more of the screen.  Of course their prebuilt view(s) (and Game Center as a whole) is really ugly and I have considered just reinventing the wheel simply so I don't have to display that stupid poker table theme.

Comment: You really need to start living within the Reality Distortion Field! :)

Comment: Lol I had to look that one up.  I was a Microsoft only user for most of my life so the equivalent in MS terms is that "Bugs are features".

Comment: I guess no one knows the answer to this so I'll give the bounty :P

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much customization available with this, you will need to get the data and display it yourself if you want that.

If you size the view to 420x512, it will display correctly.

Try something like this:

```
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.

        leaderboardController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f));
        leaderboardController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 512);
        //leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(240, 160);
        leaderboardController.view.center = CGPointMake(364, 512);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but unfortunately that does not appear to work.

Comment: which part doesn't work?  line 1 specifies iPad only execution of the code that follows.  then a few lines to show how the view of the GC Leaderboard controller can be moved.  works well for some apps.

Comment: The sizing of the view doesn't work. It just stays exactly the same size. I'm not sure why.